# Characterisation of subgroups of finite index of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: group-theory

Is there a complete characterisation of subgroups of finite index of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: This might be a good place to start: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2373006?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: The simple answer is no. Note that ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ has free subgroupsof finite index.

Comment: So-called congruence subgroups (like $\Gamma(N)$, $\Gamma_0(N)$ and $\Gamma_1(N)$) have finite index, but there are also subgroups of finite index which are not congruence subgroups.

Comment: A good survey article on this subject is this: http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3315